Hatching of dots inside the polygon not displayed on the GeoServer
I have this style in SLD format:
<se:PolygonSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
    <se:Fill>
      <se:GraphicFill>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#03f843</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#03f843</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:WellKnownName>shape://dot</se:WellKnownName>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>25</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:GraphicFill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#efefef</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Fill>
    <se:Stroke>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Stroke>
  </se:PolygonSymbolizer>

In a polygon created using this style, the points inside are not displayed.
If I change shape://dot to any other (for example shape://plus), then everything is displayed correctly inside the polygon. What's wrong with the dots? Why are they not displayed?
Logs:
[renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying fill to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying stroke to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying fill to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying stroke to mark

But the exact same thing is displayed for other characters (for example shape://vertline).
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://vertline
TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://vertline
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying fill to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying stroke to mark

But shape://vertline is displayed correctly.

What does the log file say? All I can say is it works for me - so it could be your layer or some other part of your SLD

@IanTurton I added logs to the question. I still can't figure out what's going on.Even if I select shape://dot for a regular point, nothing works anyway.

does it work for another layer? I tested it on topp:states and it was fine

@IanTurton I'm new to the geoserver, and I've been checking on my own layer.

@IanTurton Have you used exactly my style, and is everything working for you?

I converted it back to SLD 1.0 from SE but exactly what you show otherwise

@IanTurton I have installed my local geoserver. I checked, everything is working, the dots are displayed. Now I need to figure out what's wrong with the other one. Could it be that the shape://dot points themselves were deleted by someone from the geoserver? How can this be verified? As for the layers, it seems to me that it cannot be a matter of them, since the display is due to the style.

@IanTurton I understand that you have faced this problem and solved it. Do I just need to change the version? (There is issue: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-11046)

@IanTurton Or you made changes to version 2.23.1, because I experimentally installed the version locally, and the dots work...

If you are running any version that pre-dates 2.23.1 then you need to update to avoid  CVE-2024-36401
